# Vue3 - Persisting state with Page refresh

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vue-router4

I have just started using Vue3, and am trying to use vuex to manage state. when using Vue2 I would call the store each time the app loads like this:

```js
// mains.js
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import router from "./routes";

window.Vue = require('vue').default;
Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(VueMoment);
Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store(storeDefinition);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    store,
    components: {
        "index": Index
    },
    async created() {
        this.$store.dispatch("loadStoredState");
        this.$store.dispatch("loadUser");
    },
});
```

This is my vuex store that defines state, mutations and actions for vuex:

```js
// store.js
import { isLoggedIn, logOut } from "./shared/utils/auth";

export default {
    state: {
        isLoggedIn: false,
        user: {}
    },
    mutations: {
        setUser(state, payload) {
            state.user = payload;
        },
        setLoggedIn(state, payload) {
            state.isLoggedIn = payload;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        loadStoredState(context) {
            context.commit("setLoggedIn", isLoggedIn());
        },
        async loadUser({ commit, dispatch }) {
            if (isLoggedIn()) {
                try {
                    const user = (await axios.get("/user")).data;
                    commit("setUser", user);
                    commit("setLoggedIn", true);
                } catch (error) {
                    dispatch("logout");
                }
            }
        },
        logout({ commit }) {
            commit("setUser", {});
            commit("setLoggedIn", false);
            logOut();
        }
    },
    getters: {}
}
```

This file manages a cookie for local storage that stores a boolean value for isLoggedIn:

```js
// auth.js
export function isLoggedIn() {
    return localStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn") == 'true';
}

export function logIn() {
    localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", true);
}

export function logOut() {
    localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", false);
}
```

But in Vue3 I am creating the main.js file like this:

```js
// mains.js
const { createApp } = require('vue')
import Index from './Index.vue'
import createRouter from './router'
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import storeDefinition from "./store";

const store = createStore(storeDefinition)

createApp(Index)
    .use(createRouter())
    .use(store)
    .mount('#app')
```

How can I add the two calls to manage the store to the createApp function?

Comment: The store itself cannot store anything because it's client side. You need either a server, some cookies, localStorage or alike.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, the two calls are for loading state from the store

Comment: My comment is still valid. A Vuex store cannot survive a page reload if you do not persist it with something else.

Comment: Thank you, I see what you mean. I have a file that sets a cookie with isLoggedIn to true / false, I will add that to the question for clarity.

Comment: Initialization logic in V2 code is orphan. It could reside in root component, where it belongs

Comment: You can just call your functions in the setup script of `Index.vue` because `Index` is your root component and its hook is called every time you create a Vue instance.
By the way, you can actually call your function right after `createStore(storeDefinition)`. It will work but you need to watch your data to make sure when does it ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `created` hook to the root component by using the [`extends` option](https://vuejs.org/api/options-composition.html#extends) with the component definition:

```js
// main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import Index from './Index.vue'
import createRouter from './router'
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import storeDefinition from './store'

const store = createStore(storeDefinition)

createApp({
    extends: Index,
    created() {
      this.$store.dispatch('loadStoredState')
      this.$store.dispatch('loadUser')
    },
  })
  .use(createRouter())
  .use(store)
  .mount('#app')
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-init-store-from-root-component?file=src%2Fmain.js)